# Calling functions of a class via apply doesn't initialize the values in the constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have javascript classes in multiple files. I would like to call a function from a given class by only supplying their names as arguments.

```js
class Index{
    constructor(){
        this.Loader("test", "TestFunc");
    }

    Loader(cname, fname){
        const template = require(`./${cname}.js`);
        const object = new template();
        object[fname].apply();
    }
}

new Index();
```

```js
module.exports = class Test{
    constructor(){
        this.text = "this text should appear";
    }

    TestFunc(){
        console.log(this.text);
    }
}
```

When the instance of the Test class gets initialized the constructor will run and prepare the value, but when I call TestFunc via the apply function the same values appear undefined and the error "Cannot read property text of undefined" gets thrown. When calling the function normally via object.TestFunc(); no such error is present.

Comment: Why are you using `apply()`?

Comment: You are not passing a `thisArg` to `apply` - it should be `object[fname].apply(object);`

Comment: Which is basically the same as just writing `object[fname]()`.

Comment: @UnholySheep Thank you! This solves my issue.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for the advice.

Comment: You only need to use `apply()` if you need to provide a `this` value other than the object you're using to call the method.

Comment: It was also originally needed to spread an array into arguments, but ES6 added `...` for argument spreading.